# How to take a list element as an index number to print another list in Python?

Tags: python, list

How should I use a loop to print a list like this?:

```
list1 = [[1,3],[2,5],[3,6]]
list2 = [2,3,6,4,7,8,9,1]
print(list2[1:3])
print(list2[2:5])
print(list2[3:6])
```

I don't want to hardcode this programme. How can I use a loop to print the list?

Answer (score 2):

```
for start, end in list1:
    print(list2[start:end])
```